# bluetooth PCM communication is deaf

Tags: linux, command-line, bluetooth, dbus, headset

I have the following system:

bluetooth headset <-- HFP, HSP --> marvell bluetooth <-- PCM --> gsm modem

**What I know:**

*First part works:*

> rfcomm0: 00:06:C6:36:02:92 -> 00:1A:7D:D0:04:6D channel 1 connected
>   [reuse-dlc release-on-hup tty-attached]

and

> l2ping 00:1A:7D:D0:04:6D Ping: 00:1A:7D:D0:04:6D from 00:06:C6:36:02:92 (data size 44) ... 4 bytes from 00:1A:7D:D0:04:6D id
>   0 time 7.99ms 4 bytes from 00:1A:7D:D0:04:6D id 1 time 20.35ms 4 bytes
>   from 00:1A:7D:D0:04:6D id 2 time 16.65ms

*The second part also works, because:*

I measured the signals,

and in case of connecting data lines I had echo.

**But I cannot speaking via my headset-PCM system.**

*Do you have any idea where the bug can be? I am sure I have to change something on the settings.*

**My idea:**

If I open the modem port on the embedded Linux and starts a calling I hear nothing in my headset. It seems me however I have an open rfcomm serial interface for HFP, but I have no SCO connection created and maybe bluetooth chip does not forwards my PCM.

Comment: For the connection creating I used rfcomm.

Comment: If I open the modem port on the embedded Linux and starts a calling I hear nothing in my headset.
It seems me however I have an open rfcomm serial interface for HFP, but I have no SCO connection created and maybe bluetooth chip does not forwards my PCM.